Vulnerability in ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API when the library is not directly installed?
I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API. I have implemented CI/CD to release changes and also integrated a vulnerability scanning tool (tviry) into the project to check for vulnerabilities in the code. Today, I came across a strange vulnerability in a library that is not installed in the project.
To fix the vulnerability, Of course, I can install the updated version (6.0.1), but I am unsure why this issue is being flagged in the code if this library is no longer present. Is it possible that this library, System.Formats.Asn1,System.IO.Packaging,NuGet.Protocol,SortedList is being used internally by the .NET 6.0 framework?

Library: System.Formats.Asn1
Vulnerability: CVE-2024-38095
Severity: HIGH
Installed Version: 6.0.0
Fixed Version: 6.0.1, 8.0.1

Title: dotnet: DoS when parsing X.509 Content and ObjectIdentifiers
https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2024-38095

I am not a security expert, and I don't know if this library is used by the .Net internally, but if it is, you should probably update it and/or the library using it.

It seems like this might be a transitive dependency issue. One of your direct dependencies relies on it, so Trivy would detect it. Please check if any of your direct dependencies have newer versions available that you can update to.

Yes, it is used indirectly by .NET assemblies - I found this post about a new .NET 9 dotnet command, which happens to show how it works using exactly the assembly you mentioned ;-)

This is the link to that gentleman's LinkedIn profile

Wow! It shows how serious you are to help people. While most people browse LinkedIn for job and ignore such posts, you saved it to help people.
